# Visual Studio 2005: "Error: the Visual C++ Project Engine is not properly installed."

Tags: visual-studio

My VS2005 started printing the following error:

```
Error: the Visual C++ Project Engine is not properly installed. The build cannot continue. Please repair the Visual Studio installation.
```

What do I do now? Is there a way to fix this that does not require reinstalling the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by following this procedure:

1. locate this file "VCProjectEngine.dll" (vc/vcpackages)
2. re-register it by running this command on the shell ( the command window):

> regsvr32 VCProjectEngine.dll

Comment: Thanks. This saved a lot of time!